# unable to run a java program which was imported to eclipse through maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

After importing  a project to eclipse through maven. I am getting an error and program is not running. I am using JDK 7.Eclipse :kepler version. Maven 3.5.0 version.
[ Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.4:endpoints_get_discovery_doc (execution: default, phase: compile) pom.xml /helloworld line 114    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem](**THIS IS ERROR **).

[image]

Comment: You are using a plugin where there has not been written a "connector" which tells Eclipse what the plugin does.  This needs to be done for all maven plugins used for Eclipse to work - fortunately the most common ones have!  You need to tell Eclipse what to do for this plugin before the emulated maven build by Eclipse will work.

Comment: also its a good idea to show us the pom file...

Answer (score -1):

try to wrap `<plugin>` tag with `<pluginManagement>` tag at the pom.xml file

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> ... </plugin>
            <plugin> ... </plugin>
                  ....
        </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: Why would this help?